# Reach second level association with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Imagine you have three models

```
Class Garage
  has_many :drivers
end

Class Driver
  belongs_to :garage
  has_many :cars
end

Class Car
  belongs_to :driver
end
```

That's all good.

Now what if I want to add a `has_many` association between `Garage` and `Car` so that I can do directly `garage.cars` without adding a new `garage_id` key to the `Car` model ?

I am currently using a `cars` function defined in the `Garage` model:

```
def cars
  drivers.map{ |driver| driver.cars }.flatten
end
```

but that's just not satisfactory as this function returns an Array and not a Proxy and hence I cannot use named scopes on the returned cars.
Plus it is sub-optimal query-wise.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Garage
  has_many :drivers
  has_many :cars, :through => :drivers
end
```

Documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options)

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid I though this was only for many to many associations, thanks.

Comment: What if there is more than two levels?

Comment: "This can be any other type of association, including other :through associations", so just add another `has_many :something, :through => :cars`.